# How to remove <p>..</p> tag from ckEditor in java/GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, ckeditor

I have created ckeditor in GWT like:

```
CKEditor ck = new CKEditor();
```

and get the value of it like:

```
ck.getData().toString();
```

but I get the

```
<p>  DISADAD </p>
```

Now, I want to remove it.

Comment: @samir. Nothing to do with Ck editor. You have to use safe html where you are using It.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Ach, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `replaceAll` method from String class do the stuff.

I won't recommend it to do so. Because you are moving in a wrong direction.

Ck editor returns html markup in `return`.   It's your responsibilty to show that `html` where ever you want. For ex: using `safeHtml` interface in `GWT.`

If you remove that html tags from `string`  it's just visible like an normal `string`, which there is no meaning of using **ck editor.**